# MFMessageComposeViewController not calling its delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Hi i'm using MFMessageComposeViewController to send sms in my iOS project my code is like below,

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *message = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    message.delegate = self;
    message.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxxxxx"];
    message.body = @"blha blah,,,,";
    [self presentModalViewController:message animated:YES];
```

and in my code i'm defining MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate method **didFinishWithResult** but when the task is completed control is not calling this didFinishWithResult delegate method.What may be the problem?

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to set the [`mailComposeDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-SW5)

```
    message.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

Comment: Also, Make sure your class conforms to the proper delegate protocol: `<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

Comment: message.messageComposeDelegate = self;

Comment: Just out of curiosity would anyone happen to know what is the original `delegate` used for? I assume it is used for something else.

Comment: @Flying_Banana the original delegate is the UINavigationDelegate